# How to create a cornered Trapezoid in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to create a cornered Trapezoid card similar to the image for my App in Jetpack compose but don't know how to approach doing that
[Trapezoid Card Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAKRm.jpg)

I attempted to create a cornered trapezoid in Jetpack Compose using a custom Shape class.I'm aiming for a cornered trapezoid shape, and any guidance on the correct approach or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it easily:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Outline
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density

class TrapezoidShape : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: androidx.compose.ui.unit.LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        val path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(0f, 0f)
            lineTo(size.width, 0f)
            lineTo(size.width * 0.8f, size.height)
            lineTo(size.width * 0.2f, size.height)
            close()
        }
        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
}
```

And in composable function:

```
 @Composable
    fun TrapezoidCard(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
                .clip(TrapezoidShape())
                .background(Color.White)
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
```

You can even customize the value to adjust your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the shape from the Internet and extract its path.

Apps like **Figma** can also help; just drop the shape on Figma and then export it as an `svg`.  Next, open the vector drawble with VS Code or notepad and find the **`d`** attribute.

You can then create a class implementing the `Shape` interface and pass the path data to create an outline.

```
class Trapezoid :Shape{
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {

}
```

There is a detailed [blog](https://blog.devgenius.io/custom-shapes-in-jetpack-compose-deep-dive-b987a52c743c) on how to go about it.